Is it legal for US states spy on each other?
Are there known instances in which one state has infiltrated another to learn of its intentions, to promote an agenda, or to prevent an undesirable outcome?
Is this legal?
What are the penalties for such actions, should the agent be discovered?

I’m voting to close this question because it is not about law

What does "spying" mean. Most affairs of states are done publicly, and most affairs of states done privately are ones that other states wouldn't care about. This can't be answered without more specificity. Some kinds of spying might be legal, other kinds of spying might not be legal. States can't commit crimes either, although people working as agents of states can.

@littleadv Asking what the penalties are seems to make it a question about what laws govern this behavior.

State and local governments sometimes conduct secret business. This is sometimes known as "executive session" of a city council or other governing body. Each state has a list of reasons why this can be done. The most common reasons are personnel matters and property matters. There are often laws preventing employees from divulging the secret matters. Ultimately, the decisions about such information is made public, personnel decisions or property decisions, but not their discussion or reasons behind them. It seems that spying would not be very useful to other government bodies.

@ohwilleke I think this is an interesting question. You are correct that most affairs of state are done publicly, but not all, and most certainly not all are presented for public review in a timely fashion. Famously Kansas and Missouri got into a bidding war for tax incentives intended to persuade companies into relocating to their state. I can imagine there would be a strong desire to know the opposing state's strategies and bidding limits.

Another hypothetical motivation for espionage could be if one state was currently suing the other.
